# MRTK-Teleport Layer Selection on Unity

Tags: mrtk

I'm trying the Windows Mixed Reality Toolkit with Oculus Quest 2 on Unity using the hand tracking.

When i change the layer mask of a Game Object, the teleport doesn't works, it does only on the Layer 0:Default.

I searched for hours a way, red all the teleport's scripts, i find the variable but nothing happen when i change it.

here the piece of code that i found:

```
/// <summary>
/// Teleport logic will only work with TeleportPoint components that exist in the layers specified by this mask.
/// </summary>
[Tooltip("Teleport logic will only work with TeleportPoint components that exist in the layers specified by this mask.")]
public LayerMask TeleportLayerMask;
```

Answer (score 1):

The Layer Settings need to be set on the ParabolicTeleportPointer Prefab.
You will find it in the MRTK Inspector under Input => Pointers.

On the Prefab the is a "ParabolicTeleportPointer" Component. There you can set "Valid Layers" and "Invalid Layers" for the teleport.

Its very hidden. I had also opened a [Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/8958) on the git with the exact same problem before I found it.